# WordPress - Using wp_localize, but cannot get output correctly

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to use wp_localize to pull php into a js file. I can get the php to echo to a CDATA tag in the footer, but not actually into the js file, even though I'm following the advice i've seen in many places?

I have this in my functions.php file -

```
function js_enqueue_scripts() {

global $theme_options;
$site_parameters = array(
    'twitterId=' . $theme_options['divider-twitter-id']
    );

wp_register_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/js/scripts.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( "scripts" );
wp_localize_script( 'scripts', 'SiteParameters', $site_parameters );
}
add_action( "wp_enqueue_scripts", "js_enqueue_scripts" );
```

Now the variable twitterID will output the correct number as set in my theme options (ie; 39403940349403) to a CDATA tag in the footer, but not to my scripts.js file?

The code for scripts.js is as follows -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

if ($('body.default').length) {
    twitterFetcher.fetch('SiteParameters.twitterID', 'twitter-fetcher-tweet', 1, true, false);
};

});
```

Am needing the above to output as -

```
twitterFetcher.fetch('348394839438493', 'twitter-fetcher-tweet', 1, true, false);
```

But it's just not passing from functions to the js file?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare array like the syntax requires you to:

   `array( 'twitterId' => '39403940349403' );`
2. Change the Script to:

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

   if ($('body.default').length) {
       twitterFetcher.fetch(SiteParameters.twitterId, 'twitter-fetcher-tweet', 1, true, false);
   };

   });
   ```

Sometimes the biggest problems arise out of the silliest mistakes.

Just so that you know, you declared `twitterId` and trying to access it as `twitterID`.

Been there, done that.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, and well spotted with the typo ;)

But no, still not working after that change. The twitterID variable is still not getting output to the js file??

Help!!

Comment: Remove the string around it. Updated answer. This will make sure your variables are parsed., then you can convert it to string, if need be. (`.toString()`)

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far Sunny, but still no working :(

Used the updated code as above -

`jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

if ($('body.default').length) { twitterFetcher.fetch(SiteParameters.twitterId, 'twitter-fetcher-tweet', 1, true, false); };

});`

Comment: Did you also do the first change? I added an additional step.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, forgot to update the functions.php, as per your instructions. A massive thank you Sunny ;)